# Expandable divs with content inside them CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the main content and nav bar centered on the screen using `margin: 0 auto;` and I can't get the containing `<div>` to resize vertically when the content inside it does, I've tried putting `display:inline-block;` for the containing `div` and that expands but then it isn't centered anymore, and `display:block;` centers it but it no longer expands. If you look at the code you may get a better understanding, sorry if that didn't make sense, it was hard to explain. I could use a solution to either one, Thanks a lot!  PS. make sure to run the code snippet!

Here's the code

```css
#main_content {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 600px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#here_you_can_learn {
  font-size: 47px;
  color: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#welcome {
  color: white;
  font-size: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#down_arrow {
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#most_frequent {
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#m_f_heading {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#m_f_show_more {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#recent_activity {
  width: 375px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#r_a_heading {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_body {}

#r_a_show_more {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../pictures/test.jpg");
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  width: 170px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Main Nav */

#home_icon {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 95px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li a:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 24px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav li a:visited {
  color: black;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}

nav li a:active {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

nav {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=search] {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#searchbox {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #2b303b;
  border: none;
  color: #63717f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="">
      <img id="logo" src="pictures/jeff_logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>

    <a href=""><img src="pictures/home_icon.png" id="home_icon" /></a>

    <form action="" id="searchbox">
      <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
      <input type="submit" value="Search!">
    </form>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>


<!--Welcome to jeff's website-->

<div>
  <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to </br> my website!</h1>
  <a href="#here_you_can_learn">
    <img src="pictures/down_arrow.png" id="down_arrow" />
  </a>
</div>

<!--right side nav-->

<aside>
  <p>this is aside</p>

</aside>


<!--Main Content-->

<div id="main_content">
  <h2 id="here_you_can_learn">Here you can learn about me and my adventures!</h2>

  <!--Most Frequently visited pages: on left side of page-->
  <div id="most_frequent">
    <p id="m_f_heading">Most frequently visted pages!</p>



    <a href="">
      <p id="m_f_show_more">Show More</p>
    </a>

  </div>

  <!--Recent Activity: on the right side of page-->
  <div id="recent_activity">
    <p id="r_a_heading">Recent Activity</p>

    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
    <p id="r_a_body">test</p>


    <a href="">
      <p id="r_a_show_more">Show More</p>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Don't forget to run the code snippet!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened, it had an option to run code snippet the in preview mode when i was making the post, I will update!

Comment: @Paulie_D fixed!  Should work now!

Comment: I'm not sure if you ask for this, but can you try `overflow:hidden` on your `#main_content` element?

Comment: @robjez I replied to you post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```css
#main_content {
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 600px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    position: relative; top: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#here_you_can_learn {
    font-size: 47px;
    color: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#welcome {
    color: white;
    font-size: 130px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

#down_arrow {
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#most_frequent {
    width: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#m_f_heading {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}



#m_f_show_more {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}


#recent_activity {
    width: 375px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#r_a_heading {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_body {

}

#r_a_show_more {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

body {
    background-image: url("../pictures/test.jpg");
    background-color:red;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

aside {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        width: 170px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
}

/* Main Nav */
    #home_icon {
        height: 40px;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: 95px;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    li a:link {
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: times;
        font-size: 24px;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 3px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    nav li a:visited {
        color: black;
    }

    nav li a:hover {
        color: gray;
        border-color: gray;
    }

    nav li a:active {
        color: black;
        border-color: black;
    }

    nav {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }

    input[type=search] {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #searchbox {
        float: right;
        margin: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #2b303b;
        border: none;
        color: #63717f;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #logo {
        float: left;
        height: 150px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="">
            <img id="logo" src="pictures/jeff_logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>

        <a href=""><img src="pictures/home_icon.png" id="home_icon"/></a>

        <form action="" id="searchbox">
            <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
            <input type="submit" value="Search!">
        </form>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<!--Welcome to jeff's website-->

<div>
    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to </br> my website!</h1>
    <a href="#here_you_can_learn">
    <img src="pictures/down_arrow.png" id="down_arrow"/>
    </a>
</div>

<!--right side nav-->

<aside>
    <p>this is aside</p>

</aside>


<!--Main Content-->

<div id="main_content">
    <h2 id="here_you_can_learn">Here you can learn about me and my adventures!</h2>

<!--Most Frequently visited pages: on left side of page-->
    <div id="most_frequent">
        <p id="m_f_heading">Most frequently visted pages!</p>



        <a href=""><p id="m_f_show_more">Show More</p></a>

    </div>

<!--Recent Activity: on the right side of page-->
    <div id="recent_activity">
        <p id="r_a_heading">Recent Activity</p>

        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
        <p id="r_a_body">test</p>


        <a href=""><p id="r_a_show_more">Show More</p></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion/answer!  If you run the code snippet you will see that the nav bar and the content aren't aligned, as they where before.

Comment: I tried the updated version, and it works, what did you change?

Comment: @JeffArries - I took your `aside` element out of the **content flow**, by setting `position: absolute`, and `right:0`. Your problems started when you used `float:left` there as it is normally responsible for relating container to loose its "attachment" to its content. I slightly modified it. There is couple of ways of dealing with that - 1. Using `clearing` `floats`, 2. setting up `overflow: hidden` on container, and probably couple more...

Answer (score 1):

You have `#recent_activity` with `float: right;` which is making the `main_content` behave like that. You need to remove the float and also apply `vertical-align: top;` to `#most_frequent`

That will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a width for the div that you want to re-size vertically? IE:
- Set div to 500 px width
- Any content wider than 500 px (So a large piece of text for instance) should just appear on multiple lines, thus re-sizing in height.

You could also try fiddling with the height attribute of the div, by setting it to auto.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you misunderstood.  I need the containing `div` to resize vertically when the `divs` inside it resize vertically.  Maybe run the code snippet to see what I'm taking about?  And yes, I have set a width as you will see in my code.